# $T= \{\emptyset, \mathbb{N}, \{0\},\{0, 1\}, \{0, 1, 2\}, \{0, 1, 2, 3\}, \dots \}$. $(\mathbb{N}, T)$ is compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $(\mathbb{N}, T)$ a topological space, $T= \{\emptyset, \mathbb{N}, \{0\},\{0, 1\}, \{0, 1, 2\}, \{0, 1, 2, 3\}, \dots \}$.

Is $(\mathbb{N}, T)$ is compact?

And $f$ : $(\mathbb{N}, T)$ → $\mathbb{R}$ (with ordinary topology) is constant and therefore limited?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Comment: What is your definition of compacted? (Do you mean "compact"?) Where are you such applying this definition?

Comment: Use `$\{\}$` for $\{\}$.

Comment: Yes, compact. 
I do not know how to apply the definition.

Comment: Cover $\Bbb N$ with opens, for a start. Can you do that?

Comment: The infinite union of all the open ones gives me N, but I can not find any finite subrecubrimiento, no? Why would N be coating? (Since N is open too.)  @Arthur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The union of all the open sets of T except for N, covers N.
Assume  a finite subset of them covers N.
Let {0,1,..k} be the largest of that finite cover.
Show that there is a contradiction.

Comment: And the second part? How can I see that $f$ is constant?

Comment: @frees.  Clearly, as f can be any function there is no reason to for it to be constant .

Comment: @frees Look at the set $f^{-1}(\{f(0)\})$. Since $f$ is continuous, that set is …, and since it contains $0$, it follows that …

Comment: @DanielFischer.  Why is f continuous?  Nowhere was f stated to be continuous.

Comment: Good point. My autocorrection jumped ahead.